# Figure out if the improper Integral exists

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

please only give a slide hint, not the complete way to the goal, since I want to figure it out myself ;)

So given is the improper integral:

$$\displaystyle\int_{0+0}^{+\infty}  x^{\frac{\alpha}{5}}(1+x^2)^{\alpha-3}dx$$

So I want to check for which $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ my improper integral exists.

Since I couldnt figure out a good way to build the antiderivative, I figured I could evaluate:

$\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow+\infty}x^{\frac{\alpha}{5}}(1+x^2)^{\alpha-3}$ and $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow0+0}x^{\frac{\alpha}{5}}(1+x^2)^{\alpha-3}$

In order for a converging areafunction, $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow+\infty}x^{\frac{\alpha}{5}}(1+x^2)^{\alpha-3}=0$

has to hold, and $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow0+0}x^{\frac{\alpha}{5}}(1+x^2)^{\alpha-3}$ has to exists.

Now I  looked at the cases for which the exponents have a significant change in behavior.

Namely: $\alpha < 0$ and $0<\alpha<3$ and $3<\alpha$

In the case $\alpha < 0$:

$\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow0+0}x^{\frac{\alpha}{5}}(1+x^2)^{\alpha-3}=+\infty$ so is no real number! and doesnt work

In the case $3<\alpha$:

$\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow0+0}x^{\frac{\alpha}{5}}(1+x^2)^{\alpha-3}=0$

and

$\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow+\infty}x^{\frac{\alpha}{5}}(1+x^2)^{\alpha-3}=\infty$

In the case $0<\alpha<3$

$\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow0+0}x^{\frac{\alpha}{5}}(1+x^2)^{\alpha-3}=0$

$\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow+\infty}x^{\frac{\alpha}{5}}(1+x^2)^{\alpha-3}$ I could not figure out, since l'Hoptial did not help.

My assumption is that $\forall \alpha \in M \subset (0,3)$ the improper integral exists.

But .. the one limit i couldnt figure out :/ what could I try? Or is there a clever way to build the anitderivetive which I obviously dont know?

Thank you for your time and help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your conditions are not always true. Suppose that in the limit of large $x$ the function behaves like $1/x$. The limit is $0$, but the integral diverges to $\infty$. Similarly, at low $x$, the function might behave like $1/\sqrt x$. The limit of the function at $0+0$ is $+\infty$, but the integral is finite.

So how do we solve the problem. We start similarly to your approach: we split the integral in three parts, one for low $x$, one for intermediate $x$, and one for high $x$. Since the function is continuous and bounded in $[a,b]\subset(0,\infty)$, the middle integral is finite. At low $x$, we have $1+x^2\approx1$, so the corresponding integral is $$I_L=\int_0^a x^{\frac \alpha 5}dx$$
For $\alpha=-5$ you get $$I_L=\ln a-\ln 0=\infty$$
otherwise $$I_L=\frac 1{\frac\alpha 5+1}x^{\frac\alpha 5+1}\mid_0^a$$
In order for $I_L$ to be finite you need to have $$\frac\alpha 5+1\gt0$$ or $\alpha\gt -5$. Similarly, at high $x$ you have $1+x^2\approx x^2$, so $$I_H=\int_b^\infty x^{\frac\alpha 5}x^{2(\alpha-3)}dx$$
Follow the same approach to see the other condition for $\alpha$.